# use service after binding without clicking button

Tags: android

```
public class BindingActivity extends Activity {
    LocalService mService;
    boolean mBound = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        // Bind to LocalService
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, LocalService.class);
        bindService(intent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        // Unbind from the service
        if (mBound) {
            unbindService(mConnection);
            mBound = false;
        }
    }

    /** Called when a button is clicked (the button in the layout file attaches to
      * this method with the android:onClick attribute) */
    public void onButtonClick(View v) {
        if (mBound) {
            // Call a method from the LocalService.
            // However, if this call were something that might hang, then this request should
            // occur in a separate thread to avoid slowing down the activity performance.
            int num = mService.getRandomNumber();
            Toast.makeText(this, "number: " + num, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    /** Defines callbacks for service binding, passed to bindService() */
    private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className,
                IBinder service) {
            // We've bound to LocalService, cast the IBinder and get LocalService instance
            LocalBinder binder = (LocalBinder) service;
            mService = binder.getService();
            mBound = true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName arg0) {
            mBound = false;
        }
    };
}
```

this is a example in http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html. 
I want to use mService Directly and do not need to click button first, how can I do. I have tried many ways, but they are all won't work.

Comment: Can you post some of the things you've tried? That way the answers won't repeat code you've already tried.

Comment: Firstly, I tried to use button.performClick() to simulate the button click, but it doesn't work. Secondly, I use a Thread to sleep for a while, then use mService, it doesn't work either, whatever how much time it had been sleeping.

Answer (score 0):

The problem I suspect you're having is that binding to a service is asynchronous. As such, you need to wait until you have gotten the service back before you can make a call into it. If you call bindService(intent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE); from say onCreate, you probably will still not have the service at any point during the activity boot up lifecycle... mService will still be null. If you don't want to let the user do this waiting for you (by taking a couple seconds to hit the button) you can simply make a call from your onServiceConnected method to mService and it should work fine. Either way, the key is to wait to make any calls to mService, until onServiceConnected has been run and mService is no longer null. (This will probably happen *after* even onResume). Does that make sense?

Comment: Firstly, I tried to use button.performClick() to simulate the button click, but it doesn't work. Secondly, I use a Thread to sleep for a while, then use mService, it doesn't work either, whatever how much time it had been sleeping.

Comment: Is the onServiceConnected method ever getting called? If it is never called the you probably have a problem elsewhere in your code. Try putting a breakpoint inside that method and see if you ever hit it?